# How to update a SQL Table do avoid many to many relations

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have the following table :

```
Country_ID  Area_ID
CO::BE       100
CO::BY       120
CO::CA       120
CO::CH       100
CO::CH       110
CO::CH       110
CO::IT       120
```

The relation between `Area_ID` and `Country_ID` is **one to many**. An `Area_ID` can have more `Country_ID` but a `Country_ID` must have only **one** `Area_ID`.

Many to many relation like `country_ID` `CO::CH` need to be resolved. 
So i need a procedure to identify these records and update the `Area_ID` to the most recurrent `Area_ID` for that `Country_ID` (in the example above to 110)

Please could you help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that if you only have one table there is *no relations* as relations are between *two* tables. What you are looking for is a *constraint* like the UNIQUE INDEX suggested in the response.

Answer (score 0):

> `Country_ID` must have only one `Area_ID`

In the future, to ensure that, create a UNIQUE INDEX on `Country_ID`.

To find countries that currently violates that rule:

```
 SELECT `Country_ID`
   FROM `table`
  GROUP BY `Country_ID`
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

To see all records for those countries:

```
SELECT *
  FROM `table`
 WHERE `Country_ID` in (
          SELECT `Country_ID`
            FROM `table`
           GROUP BY `Country_ID`
          HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

The statistical term for what you want is the *mode*.  You can define it using `row_number()`:

```
select country_id, area_id
from (select country_id, area_id,
             row_number() over (partition by country_id order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by contry_id
     ) ca
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you actually wanted to change the table, then you would need an `update` statement.  The exact syntax would depend on the database.